# Renewcommand labelitem doesn't work with multiple languages

Tags: lists, languages

I'm having troubles with the bullets for `itemize`.
I need to have one part of my document in English and one part in French. Therefore I use:

```
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
```

then in my document I use when it's needed:

```
\selectlanguage{english}
\selectlanguage{french}
```

I also used in the preamble:

```
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\bullet$}
```

And the result is that in my list I do not have a bullet but a dash! And I would like a bullet.

Something I noticed is that if I only use

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}
```

(so the entire document is in English) the problem disappears and I have the bullets.
But I need both English and French because of the word "chapter" and "chapitre" for example.

So does anyone have a solution to be able to use bullets for the lists in a document with English and French?

Here is a working example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
%\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\bullet$}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{english}

\chapter{First chapter}

This is my list :

 \begin{itemize}
    \item Value 1
    \item Value 2
 \end{itemize}

 \selectlanguage{french}
 \chapter{Second chapitre}

 Ceci est ma liste:

 \begin{itemize}
    \item Valeur 1
    \item Valeur 2
 \end{itemize}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Welcome to the site. In order to help it would be a *lot* better if you would please provide a fill minimale example that we can copy to our own systems and try in order to see if we get the same problematic result as you describe.

Comment: As you advised I added a working example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is `french` mocking about, try adding this

```
\addto\captionsenglish{
  \renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\bullet$}
}
```

Basically `french` alters lists, but `english` does not (AFAIR). So we add such a switch back to `english`

---

Edit, to ignore `french` all together, use

```
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{label=\textbullet}
```

`enumitem` is a very good package to know, the `shortlabels` option makes it a 1-1 replacement for the `enumerate` package.

Comment: I tried your solution. It's changes the bullets for the english part but not the french part. I also added    addto\captionsfrench{}   and it still doesn't work for the french part.

Comment: @user1314776, see the update

Comment: Perfect! That works for both now! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks a lot, the second part did the trick ! But seriously Latex...

Answer (score 5):

Use `\frenchbsetup{StandardItemLabels=true}`, so `babel-french` will not use French style itemized lists.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\frenchbsetup{StandardItemLabels=true}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{english}

\chapter{First chapter}

This is my list:

\begin{itemize}
\item Value 1
\item Value 2
\end{itemize}

\selectlanguage{french}

\chapter{Second chapitre}

Ceci est ma liste:

\begin{itemize}
\item Valeur 1
\item Valeur 2
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

(I used a devious trick to get the output in a single page, not shown here.) Note that with French it is highly recommended to have `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`. I can't recommend `utf8x`.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `iflang` package, together with `enumitem`, instead of `enumerate`. Note that maybe you'll also have to specify spacings as `frenchb`hands over to enumitem. If you want to come back with the bullet symbol, even in the French part, just use `\setlistitemize,1]{label=\textbullet}`. Btw, I think the itemize marker in french should be an `endash`.

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\usepackage{iflang}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlist[itemize, 1]{label = \IfLanguageName{french}{\textendash}{\textbullet}}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{english}

\chapter{First chapter}

This is my list :

 \begin{itemize}
    \item Value 1
    \item Value 2
 \end{itemize}

 \selectlanguage{french}
 \chapter{Second chapitre}

 Ceci est ma liste:

 \begin{itemize}
    \item Valeur 1
    \item Valeur 2
 \end{itemize}


 \chapter{Chapitre troisième}

\setlist[itemize, 1]{label = \textbullet}
 Ceci est ma liste:

 \begin{itemize}
    \item Valeur 1
    \item Valeur 2
 \end{itemize}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why `utf8x` instead of `utf8`? And why package `ucs` (same question as `ucs` is loaded by `utf8x`)?

Comment: @cgnieder: I don't know. It was in the O.P.'s minimal example, and I left it as is. But you're right: I already removed unnecessary packages, I'll change my answer at once.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback on the packages. I am not an expert in latex and I cam across codes that used these packages this way so I kept this (bad) habit. But I'll correct it. Regarding the solution, it works for the english part but not the french part.

Comment: Actually the edit made by @daleif (above) corrected the problem.

Comment: @user1314776: do you mean *you* do not have dashes for the French part, as I get with my example?

Comment: Yes I did have dashes but I wanted bullets actually.

Comment: If you want bullets everywhere, it's simpler. Any of the other solutions will work. I'll change my answer in a moment to show how to incorporate this with `enumitem`.

Answer (score 1):

The `babel` package performs various tasks in a delayed manner, i.e., when the `\begin{document}` instruction is encountered. To get your (re)definition of `\labelitemi` to work, you also need to delay it. Thus, replace

```
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\bullet$}
```

with

```
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\bullet$}}
```

or, better yet, with

```
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\textbullet}}
```

(If you want a solution that works explicitly with `babel` than around it, see the posting of @daleif.)